# disabling gzip if etag exists in proxy_pass response

Tags: nginx, gzip, etag

I'm new to nginx.

Is there a way to disable gzip if proxy_pass reutrns the ETag header.

I.E:

```
gzip on;
.
.
.

    location /foo/bar {
      proxy_pass http://server:123;

      if ($upstream_http_etag) {
         gzip off;
      }
    }
```

Basically I'm looking for a workaround to this bug that will disable the gzip compression if server responded with etag header.

http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/377

Thank you,
Vitaly

Comment: This question has been asked in the mailing list a while ago but left without an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now, [gzip_proxied](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip_proxied) has `no_etag` parameter:

```
gzip on;
gzip_proxied no_etag;
```

The bug is closed, too.