# Nginx using etags with gzipped content when proxying

Tags: caching, nginx, proxy, cache-control

I want to use nginx to be a proxy between clients and a set of my apps, the problem I encountered is:

- I have an app(on different machine than nginx) that is having static content(images, css etc.)
- That static content is gzipped
- I configured nginx as follows:

  ```
  location ^~ /static/  {
      etag on;
      expires 1d;
      more_set_headers "Vary: Accept-Encoding";

      location ~* \.(css|js)$ {
          gzip_static on;
          expires -1;
          proxy_pass   http://my_upstream;
      }
      proxy_pass   http://my_upstream;
  }
  ```

and I was expecting to have etags working for things like js and css but they are not. I'm supposing it's because that js and css files are not on the same machine as nginx and it's the problem that gzip_static on suppose to fix.

So basically my question is, is it possible to have it working that way? And if it is how to do it:)

Comment: Related question: [disabling gzip if etag exists in proxy_pass response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554920/disabling-gzip-if-etag-exists-in-proxy-pass-response).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this forum post](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,242807,242811), `etag on` is not compatible with a `proxy_pass` that may modify the response (as `gzip_static` does):

> The ETag header used in it's strong from means that it must be
>   changed whenever bits of an entity are changed. This basically
>   means that ETag headers have to be removed by filters which change
>   a response content.

As suggested in that same post, passing through `Last-Modified` will usually be enough for clients to make conditional requests.

Comment: Why does `gzip_static` modify the response? Did you mistake it with `gzip on` ?